# C++ character and strings

Tags: c++

I have been stuck in the same spot for my program and I would love it if someone could help me. I am having trouble with writing code for inserting a string into a output stream. The definition I used for the operator is:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const String&);
```

I am stuck on how to go about coding this part.

Comment: It will be difficult to help without knowing the details of `String`.

Comment: If you try posting your code... people can probably help :)

Comment: /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: operator <<
Insert string into output stream
----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
ostream& operator<<(ostream& Out, cont String& char);
{
  Out<<//Incomplete
  return Out;
}

This is what I have thus far for the output function.

Comment: @LatrishaJohnson, This might help: http://imgur.com/BUgAlGO

Comment: I assume `String` is not a `std::string` and I assume this is a learning exercise? If so, what is `String`'s interface?

Answer (score -2):

From the top of my head. Here is how you do it:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream stream, string String){
stream << String;}
```

Comment: That's already been done (and should use a reference on the first parameter, a const reference on the second, and return a value). I presume this is the OP's own string class.

Comment: This looks like a recursive call.